# Java I need three decimal places but do not want to round off

Tags: java

I am posting my code.  I do not want my answer round up.  Example:
In the second column for feet it should be 65.574, not 65.580.

```
public class Exercise_06_09 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.printf("%-15s%-15s|    %-15s%-15s\n","Feet","Meters","Meters","Feet");
        System.out.println( String.format("%62s"," ").replace(' ', '-'));

        for (double m = 20, f = 1  ; f <=10; f++, m+=5) {           
            System.out.printf("%-15.1f%-15.3f|    %-15.1f%-15.3f\n", f, footToMeter(f), m, meterToFoot(m));
        }        
    }

    //Convert from meter to foot
    public static double meterToFoot(double meter) {
        return 3.279 * meter;
    }

    //Convert from foot to meter
    public static double footToMeter(double foot) {
        return  0.305 * foot;
    }    
}
```

This is the output I get

### Feet           Meters         |    Meters         Feet

1.0            0.305          |    20.0           65.580
2.0            0.610          |    25.0           81.975
3.0            0.915          |    30.0           98.370
4.0            1.220          |    35.0           114.765
5.0            1.525          |    40.0           131.160
6.0            1.830          |    45.0           147.555
7.0            2.135          |    50.0           163.950
8.0            2.440          |    55.0           180.345
9.0            2.745          |    60.0           196.740
10.0           3.050          |    65.0           213.135

Comment: It's not an *output* problem. The value your `meterToFoot` function is calculating **is** 65.58, not 65.574. Because 20 x 3.279 is 65.58 (just work it out: 20 x 3.279 is 2 x 10 x 3.279 which is 2 x 32.79 which if we do the whole and fractional parts separately is 2 x 32 + 2 x 0.79, which is 64 + 1.58, which is 65.58).

Comment: You might want to check your math on `3.279 * 20` again

Comment: Yes, when I do the math it is 65.58, but the example in the book shows my outcome should be 65.574?

Comment: So they have a more precise factor?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `BigDecimal` class if you don't want to round off to a number.

Use something like:

```
BigDecimal bigDecimal = new BigDecimal(3.279 * meter);
```

You would get the following output:
65.5799999999999982946974341757595539093017578125

Now convert the value to String and get the substring where the end index is 3 decimal places after decimal point.

Answer (score 0):

You could multiple by 10^n ( n being the amount of digits to keep ) and then get rid of the decimals. Maybe cast it as an int. Then divide it by 10^n again.